# Sort values in HashMap by using Comparator with user defined objects

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, treemap

I have a HashMap as follows:

```
public class MyHashMapOfEmployees {

  public static void main(String a[]){
    Map<String,Employee> allEmployees= new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    allEmployees.put(new Employee("111",("Ram", "Smith", "developer"));
    allEmployees.put(new Employee("222",("John", "Doe", "manager"));
    allEmployees.put(new Employee("333",("Lisa", "Hart", "CEO"));
    allEmployees.put(new Employee("444",("Mark", "Wayman", "VP"));
  }
}
```

Here is my Employee class:

```
class Employee{    

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String position;
private String id;

public Employee(String fn, String ln, String p){
    this.firstName = fn;
    this.lastName = ln;
    this.position = p;
}     
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public String getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

I need to sort my HashMap by employees first name, and keys (id) can be omitted. Final output should be as follows:

```
John Doe manager
Lisa Hart CEO
Mark Wayman VP
Ram Smith developer
```

I tried using the following comparator:

```
private final Comparator<Employee> employeeComparator = new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        return o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName());
    }
};
```

How can I sort this HashMap not by the value (which in my case is an object - Employee), but by a particular field in my object (firstName)?

Is TreeMap not the right solution?

I've searched through stackOverflow and there is nothing for this particular scenario that I could apply and get to work. THIS ISN'T A DUPLICATE, the link that is being offered in comments is a different task.

Can I do the following without creating a TreeMap in between?

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Employee>> employeesSortedByFirstName = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Employee>>(employeeComparator()); 

employeesSortedByFirstName.addAll(allEmployees.entrySet());
```

Would this sort my map values by first name?... or by the order of insertion?..

OR - do I need a TreeMap in between as such:

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Employee>> employeesSortedByFirstName = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Employee>>(employeeComparator());

SortedMap<String, Employee> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Employee>();
sortedMap.putAll(allEmployees); //hashmap into treemap
employeesSortedByFirstName.addAll(sortedMap.entrySet()); //add treemap into the sorted set
```

THE GOAL IS TO SORT BY FIRST NAME, NOT BY THE WHOLE VALUE OF THE MAP.

Comment: Does your error look like this by any chance: *The method employeeComparator() is undefined for the type [ClassName]*

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value

Comment: If it must insert new entries at correct position when put (automatically), you could write your own map implementation. Otherwise you can just use a `LinkedHashMap` and put the entries in correct order.

Comment: the link above sorts by the whole value. My value is an object, and I need to search by a particular field in that object. that's where I can't find a solution.

Comment: @AmieChu You can just use your `employeeComparator` to compare the values.

Comment: But the way I have my SortedSet built - will it sort by first name or by order of insertion?